# How to make a html box appear on page using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I open an section of html with an id using JS/JQuery?

Lets say the html I want to trigger with JS/JQuery is

```
<section class="modal--show" id="show"
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="label-show" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-inner">
        <header>
            <h2 id="label-show">A modal</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Content.</p>
               <div id="badgeselect">

        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</section>
```

I've tried using

```
 $('#show').dialog('open');
```

which doesn't work. The only other consideration is, that the full code must also copy an image that the user clicks on (to activate `show`)

I have this at the moment, the only part not working is making the above code show on the page after the user has clicked the image.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
            $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');

              $('#show').dialog('open');

            });
            SaveMyBadge();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: what do you mean appear on page. Is it hidden and you want to display it after some event?

Comment: @Fyre sorry, yes thats correct. Basically after the user has clicked the img on the page the pop up box should appear

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? What version of jquery UI are you using?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe no console error, I'm using 1.10.2

Comment: @Dano007 did you include bootstrap? where is this `.dialog` method coming from? Its not native to JavaScript.. Are you using jQuery UI or some other library? If yes, then please mention.

Comment: @LuckySoni no, should I?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dialog` is not a native method available in JavaScript. If you want a `modal` out of the box then i recommend using a JavaScript Library which comes with such features built in. Twitter's bootstrap will be a good option.

To get started:
In your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Include this script after you include jQuery

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal Markup -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

To launch the modal

```
$('#modal').modal({'show':true});
```

[Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com)

**UPDATE:**

```
$('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
    $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
    $('#modal').modal({'show':true});
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, this would also let me pass in data captured from the user click ie the image?

Comment: @Dano007 yes, the `modal` method can be called anywhere.. so feel free to do whatever you were doing earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing div tag.

```
<div id="badgeselect">
```

is never closed. That could be causing some strange issues

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just add a click listener to the img and change the css class of the section.
The css class could have display:block

and as you stated its a pop up you could set its position in your class along with other properties such as opacity or simply

```
document.getElementById("show").style.display = block;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("show").className = "MyClass";

.MyClass{
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-width/2;
   margin-top:-height/2;
   opacity:0.8;
}
```

This should create a pop up like feature.